# Getting iframe body html content in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with getting the HTML content of an iframe.

**JQuery:**

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var template_html = $("#get_template_html").contents().find('body').html();
        alert(template_html);
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="get_template_html" src="templates/1.html"></iframe>
```

This works good in Mozilla Firefox, but in Google Chrome it shows blank alert window.

What could be the reason?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like the iframe is not fully loaded, try using instead of document ready: `$(window').on('load', function(){...});` or just bind iframe onload event and set logic there

Comment: Tried with `<script defer>` but with no success.

Comment: `defer` shouldn't help you in this case

Comment: Should I try to check if iframe is completely loaded?

Comment: Ya, you should use: `$(function(){$("#get_template_html").on('load', function(){alert($(this).contents().find('body').html());});});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onload` to your iframe, and call the JS function.

Your JS:

```
function afterLoading(){
    var template_html = $("#get_template_html").contents().find('body').html();
    alert(template_html);
}
```

Your HTML

```
<iframe id="get_template_html" src="templates/1.html" onload="afterLoading();"></iframe>
```

Comment: God bless you :)